# How to find lower envelope of a sinusoidal signal?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have a sinusoidal signal which is distorted by some random noise. I want to find out the lower envelope of the signal. I've used `abs(Hilbert(y(t)))` in MATLAB to find out an envelope but it only gives me the upper envelope. Is there any easy way to find the lower envelope of the signal?

I've also tried MATLAB inbuilt `envelope` function to find out the lower envelope but it's not working.

`y(t)` is composed of four signals.
I've to find out upper and lower envelope of the signal.

```
y(t) = A1 sin(2πf1t) + A2 sin(2πf2t) + A3 sin(2πf3t) + A4 rand()
```

```
clc
clear all
A1 = 5;
A2 = 10;
A3 = 15;
A4 = 10;
f1 = 5*10^6;
f2 = 10*10^6;
f3 = 20*10^6;
t=1:1:100
y =A1*sin(2*pi*f1*t)+A2*sin(2*pi*f2*t)+A3*sin(2*pi*f3*t)+A4*rand(1,100);
plot(t,y);
%% for upper envelope and lower envelope
upper_envelope = abs(hilbert(y));
hold on
plot(t,upper_envelope,'-r');
lower_envelope = -abs(hilbert(y));
hold on
plot(t,lower_envelope,'-g');
```

Comment: Lower envelope of `y(t)` is closely related to the upper envelope of `-y(t)`...

Comment: I've already tried that but the result doesn't seem satisfactory.

Comment: Why is it not satisfactory?  Update your question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for but I'll take a shot at it. If you negate `y` then you end up in the negative domain which causes problems when using `abs`. To avoid this we can negate `y` then add some constant to make it positive again. We take the constant to be some upper bound, in this case twice the maximal value. We flip and translate the signal such that it is positive, then compute the upper envelope on the flipped signal. Next we reverse the translation and flip again to get back to the original signal coordinates.

```
plot(t,y);
%% for upper envelope and lower envelope
upper_envelope = abs(hilbert(y));
ub = max(upper_envelope)*2;
hold on
plot(t,upper_envelope,'-r');
lower_envelope = ub-abs(hilbert(ub-y));
hold on
plot(t,lower_envelope,'-g');
```